# React leaflet Cannot find path to 'pathtofile'

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I've got a geojson file that contains paths to icons like this.

```
"features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "ICON": ".././assets/images/marker-icon.png"
```

I'm mapping the geojson file and am trying to set the icon paths with this:

```
const markers = geojson.features.map((features, i) => {
    const greenIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: require(`${features.properties.ICON}`)
    })
```

But I get the following error in console

```
Cannot find module '.././assets/images/marker-icon.png'
```

I'm trying to understand why this works:

```
  iconUrl: require(.././assets/images/marker-icon.png)
```

But when i'm mapping this doesn't:

```
iconUrl: require(`${features.properties.ICON}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the geojson for image path "ICON" to:

```
"ICON": "marker-icon.png"
```

And then changing the below worked:

```
iconUrl: require(`.././assets/images/${features.properties.ICON}`)
```